# Using Task.Run() for hardware interfacing thread invocations

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5

I need to invoke a method that meets the following criteria.

- The method may run for hours.
- The method may interface with hardware.
- The method may request user input (parameter values, confirmation, etc). The request should block the method until input has been received.

I have a prototype implementation that fulfills this criteria using the following design.

Assume a `Form` exists and contains a `Panel`.

The `IntegerInput` class is a `UserControl` with a `TextBox` and a `Button`.

```
public partial class IntegerInput : UserControl
{
  public TaskCompletionSource<int> InputVal = new TaskCompletionSource<int>(0);

  public IntegerInput()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    int val = 0;

    Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out val);

    InputVal.SetResult(val);
  }
}
```

The `Form1UserInput` class is instanced by `Form1`. The `container` is a `Panel` set by `Form1` before being provided to the invoking class.

```
public interface IUserInput
{
  Task<int> GetInteger();
}

public class Form1UserInput : IUserInput
{
  public Control container;

  private IntegerInput integerInput = new IntegerInput();
  public IntegerInput IntegerInput { get { return integerInput; } }

  public async Task<int> GetInteger()
  {
    container.Invoke(new Action(() => 
      { 
        container.Controls.Clear();
        container.Controls.Add(integerInput); 
      }));

    await integerInput.InputVal.Task;

    return integerInput.InputVal.Task.Result;
  }
}
```

The `Demo` class contains the method I want to invoke.

```
public class Demo
{
  public IUserInput ui;

  public async void MethodToInvoke()
  {
    // Interface with hardware...

    // Block waiting on input
    int val = await ui.GetInteger(); 

    // Interface with hardware some more...
  }

  public async void AnotherMethodToInvoke()
  {
    // Interface with hardware...

    // Block waiting on multiple input
    int val1 = await ui.getInteger();
    int val2 = await ui.getInteger();

    // Interface with hardware...
  }
}
```

This is a rough outline of what the invoking class looks like. The call to `Task.Run()` is accurate for my prototype.

```
public class Invoker
{
  public async Task RunTestAsync(IUserInput ui)
  {
    object DemoInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Demo));
    MethodInfo method = typeof(Demo).GetMethod("MethodToInvoke");
    object[] args = null;

    ((IUserInput)DemoInstance).ui = ui;

    var t = await Task.Run(() => method.Invoke(DemoInstance, args));

    // Report completion information back to Form1
  }
}
```

The `Form1` controller class instances the `Invoker` and calls `RunTestAsync` passing in an instance of `Form1UserInput`.

I am aware of some concerns about long running Tasks that may block and what that would mean for `ThreadPool` resources. However, the ability to invoke multiple methods at once is not provided by the application I am building. It's possible that the application may provide some other limited functionality while the invoked method is running but the current requirements do not specify such functionality in detail. I anticipate that there would only be one long running thread in service at any time.

Is the use of Task.Run() for this type of method invocation a reasonable implementation? If not, what would a more reasonable implementation be that provides for the required criteria? Should I consider a dedicated thread outside of the ThreadPool for this invocation?

Comment: Stop doing `async void` the only time it is acceptable to use is when you have a event handler and you can't change the return type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the use of Task.Run() for this type of method invocation a reasonable implementation?

Assuming that your "interface with hardware" can only be done using *synchronous* APIs, then yes, `Task.Run` is fine for that.

However, I would change *when* it's called. Right now, `Task.Run` is wrapping an `async void` method that executes on the thread pool (and uses `Invoke` to jump back on the UI thread). These are each problematic: `Task.Run` over `async void` will seem to complete "early" (i.e., at the first `await`); and using `Invoke` indicates that there's some tight coupling going on (UI calls background service which calls UI).

I would replace the `async void` with `async Task` and also change where `Task.Run` is used to avoid `Invoke`:

```
public async Task<int> GetInteger()
{
  container.Controls.Clear();
  container.Controls.Add(integerInput); 

  // Note: not `Result`, which will wrap exceptions.
  return await integerInput.InputVal.Task;
}


public async Task MethodToInvokeAsync()
{
  await Task.Run(...); // Interface with hardware...

  // Block waiting on input
  int val = await ui.GetInteger(); 

  await Task.Run(...); // Interface with hardware some more...
}


var t = await (Task)method.Invoke(DemoInstance, args);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "`Task.Run` over `async void` will seem to complete "early""? Does `await` function differently on `async void`?

Comment: @OttPrime: `async void` does not return a "handle", so `Task.Run` cannot know when the method completes. So the task returned by `Task.Run` will complete when it hits the first `await`, not when the whole `async void` method is complete.

Comment: I implemented your suggestion and I see what you mean about the invocation not being needed. However, I have methods where multiple inputs are required and in those cases, the second `await`ed block runs immediately after the first input is received rather than blocking for all inputs. I've added an example to the `Demo` class above as `AnotherMethodToInvoke`. Should the second call to `ui.GetInteger()` continue to block?

Comment: I think I see the issue. I'm attempting to reuse the same `Task` instance through the call to `GetInteger`. I modified my production code to have the call construct a new `TaskCompletionSource` and return that as the `Task` to `await. It working with that implementation.